# PowerShell - New-SPWeb with UniquePermissions

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I want to create a new SPWeb with PowerShell.
My code creates the site and add the group to the site but not the user "TestUser1".
The test\testuser1 belongs not to the TestGroup1 and get intepend permissions.

```
 $web = New-spweb http://http:/mysharepointurl/site/web -Template "STS#0" -UniquePermissions 

$user = $web.EnsureUser('test\testuser4')

$web.Users.AddUser($user, "Full") #Not working, Add a existing User

$newGroup = $web.SiteGroups["TestGroup6"] #Working, Add a existing Group
$web.Roles["Full"].AddGroup($newGroup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working solution:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://http:/mysharepointurl/site/web" 
$user = $web.AllUsers["test\testuser1"]
$roledef = $web.RoleDefinitions["Vollzugriff"]
$roleass = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($user)
$roleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roledef)
$web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleass)
$web.Update()
```

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

`$web.Users.Add` -or- `$web.AllUsers.Add`

```
public void Add(
    string loginName,
    string email,
    string name,
    string notes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection.add.aspx

Comment: $web.AllUsers.Add worked for me - thanks! The regular Add method threw an InvalidOperationException with the message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Answer (score 1):

You are using `New-SPWeb`, so that means you need to be adding users to the `SPWeb`.

`$web.SiteUsers` is the site collection group

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx

You should use

```
$web.Users
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.users.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had modified my code, but it is not working. I have not found any methode to add a user to my web object. Can you explain little bit more please?